# Developing iPhone App that will run on all the iPhone devices

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have to develop an app that should run on all the iPhone devices, whether it is iPhone 4/4S, iPhone 5/5S, or iPhone 6/6+, using Xcode 6.1.1. Will an app developed using Storyboard  run on devices prior to iPhone 5?

If not, then what things should I consider so that app will run seamlessly on all the iPhone devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboard and ARC will work till iOS 5.

Apple Document:
[Storyboard Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/)

Note: This are Some Nice Tutorials About AutoLayout.

[AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/),
[raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt with Size classes and auto layout. First I didn't know how autolayout and sizeclasses work, and it was so tough for me. Yeah, now the problem with multiple screen is not a big deal anymore.

Please read apple's docs:

[Auto Layout Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
[Size Classes Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html)

Comment: ok..thanks...I will give it a try. What I understood that Storyboard is mainly concerned with iOS version and not with iPhone devices. So if a user is having iPhone 4/4S with at least iOS 5 then Storyboard based app will run without a problem. Please correct if I am wrong.